# iOS swift 4.0 print from BLE thermal printer

Tags: ios, swift, printing, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to take print out from thermal printer by using BLE command from iOS App. For that, I have used Printer library from COCOAPODS. I am using cashino ptp-ii printer to take print out from. In my code when I start printing data(Image) on button click, printer just starts printing blank pages and doesn't stop printing and I've to manually turn it off to stop it. Below is my code that I've used to print:

```
  let image = UIImage(named: "demo")!

    if pm.canPrint {

        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {

            var receipt = Receipt(
                data
            )

            receipt.feedLinesOnTail = 2
            receipt.feedPointsPerLine = 60
            pm.print(receipt)
        }

    } else {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowSelectPrintVC", sender: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Which printer library? Link?

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Printer

Comment: That library doesn't seem to have any documentation, but the example in the library shows the creation of a `Receipt` object that contains items, including an image. This is then sent to the printer. I suspect what you are doing is just sending the raw jpeg data bytes to the printer.

Comment: Yes because Receipt object expects Data form and that is being sent. Am I doing wrong? And what should I modify if I want to print pdf directly? Do you have any reference to any other sdk/library?

Comment: It accepts data, but I presume that data needs to be in ESC/P format which is why it provides the `Receipt` extension to `Data` (which isn't a design choice I would have made) that can encode various object types for you.

Comment: Can you provide me the sample code, it would help me out a way better

Comment: How the data have to send, depends on the printer language the printer supports. Some printers accept ESC/P, other ZPL, TLS or other. Usually you find details about the format in the  "Programming" or "Command Reference manual" of the device.) Some devices accept multiple languages, which have to be selected in the device first. Some (very simple/cheap) devices only use a small part of a printer language like only ESC/P image transfer. if you have nothing, but need ESC/P you can google for an epson ESC/P Command Reference Manual